# Combining Three Plus/Minus Buttons With Five Number Counters

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per title I have three plus/minus buttons, the three buttons have to be independent from each other i.e when one is clicked the output in the other two is not affected. All three need to show their total output in the two stand alone outputs.
I've researched this and tried some trial and error stuff with no luck as yet. I hope I've explained myself OK, Pen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjeGQy and code below. I can use jquery if that helps.

```
<input type="text" value="0" class="count"><br><br>
<input type="text" value="0" class="count"><br><br>

<input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus()">
<input type="text" value="0" class="count">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus()"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus()">
<input type="text" value="0" class="count">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus()"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus()">
<input type="text" value="0" class="count">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus()"> 

var count = 1;
    var countEl = document.querySelectorAll(".count");
    function plus(){
        count++;
        countEl.value = count;
    }
    function minus(){
      if (count > 1) {
        count--;
        countEl.value = count;
      }
```

Update

Thanks for your answers so far. To clarify what I'm trying to achieve as it's quite complex to explain:
The three button/counters could at anytime have three different outputs, say 1 2 3 totalling 6, that 6 needs to be shown in the two standalone counters with this number being added to or taken away from every time the button/counters are used.

Update1

New code and Pen, please see my comment below

```
<input type="number" name="quantity1" value="0">
<input type="number" name="quantity1" value="0"><br><br><br>

<input type="button" class="" data-quantity="minus" data-field="quantity1" value="-">
<input type="number" name="quantity1" value="0">
<input type="button" class="" data-quantity="plus" data-field="quantity1" value="+">

<input type="button" class="" data-quantity="minus" data-field="quantity2" value="-">
<input type="number" name="quantity2" value="0">
<input type="button" class="" data-quantity="plus" data-field="quantity2" value="+">

<input type="button" class="" data-quantity="minus" data-field="quantity3" value="-">
<input type="number" name="quantity3" value="0">
<input type="button" class="" data-quantity="plus" data-field="quantity3" value="+">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // This button will increment the value
  $('[data-quantity="plus"]').click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr("data-field");
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($("input[name=" + fieldName + "]").val());
    // If is not undefined
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      // Increment
      $("input[name=" + fieldName + "]").val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $("input[name=" + fieldName + "]").val(0);
    }
  });
  // This button will decrement the value till 0
  $('[data-quantity="minus"]').click(function(e) {
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    fieldName = $(this).attr("data-field");
    // Get its current value
    var currentVal = parseInt($("input[name=" + fieldName + "]").val());
    // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      // Decrement one
      $("input[name=" + fieldName + "]").val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      // Otherwise put a 0 there
      $("input[name=" + fieldName + "]").val(0);
    }
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwOLNL

Comment: You're thinking about a bunch of buttons and a bunch of inputs. That approach will not give you what you want. Instead, try thinking of the combination of plus/count/minus elements as a single widget, and contain them as such? Take a look at my answer to see how that might help.

Comment: I didn't want anyone to think I've been sitting around on my arse waiting for answers to roll in so I've done a bit more research and come up with something else. Its nearly there but I'm struggling to work out how to add the three button/counter totals up and display that in the two counter above. Code and new Pen in Update1 above.

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged this jQuery, I'm using jQuery to facilitate some parts. And I'm not sure why you'd need to output the same data to multiple locations, but that should be pretty painless too.

EDIT NOTE: You indicate in your comment that you want the three fields to sum (add all three values) rather than concatenate (create a string of all three values). That's actually a very minor change, simply change the processing within the loop where we iterate over all the plusMinusWidgets. It's a matter of removing the comma line, and changing how we combine the fields into the resultEl field -- by default, they're treated as a string. I've edited the code to cast (force) them into a Number value, and add them to the current resultEl field (which I also cast into a Number value).

```js
var resultEl = $(".resultSet");

$(".plusMinusThing").on("click", ".minusBtn", function(){
  var currentWidget = $(this).parents(".plusMinusThing");
  var countEl = currentWidget.find(".count");
  countEl.val(Number(countEl.val())-1);
  countEl.trigger("change");
}).on("click", ".plusBtn", function(){
  var currentWidget = $(this).parents(".plusMinusThing");
  var countEl = currentWidget.find(".count");
  countEl.val(Number(countEl.val())+1);
  countEl.trigger("change");
}).on("change keyup", ".count", function(){
  resultEl.val("");
  /******
   * This is the only piece changed in order to sum the fields,
   *   rather than concatenate them. I've removed the comma,
   *   and I've cast the element values to numbers, then added.
   ******/
  $(".plusMinusThing").each(function(index, element){
    // Set the value of the resultEl to itself plus the next
    //  count el. Note it will work if the value is negative.
    resultEl.val( Number(resultEl.val() ) + Number($(element).find(".count").val() ) );
  })
})
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="results">
  <input type="text" class="resultSet" />
</fieldset>
<hr/>
<fieldset class="plusMinusThing">
  <input type="button" class="minusBtn" value="-">
  <input type="text" value="0" class="count">
  <input type="button" class="plusBtn" value="+">
  <br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="plusMinusThing">
  <input type="button" class="minusBtn" value="-">
  <input type="text" value="0" class="count">
  <input type="button" class="plusBtn" value="+">
  <br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="plusMinusThing">
  <input type="button" class="minusBtn" value="-">
  <input type="text" value="0" class="count">
  <input type="button" class="plusBtn" value="+">
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

Much the same thing **is** an option without jQuery, although it is a bit more complicated. The following presents much the same functionality. Biggest difference is that I don't output to multiple target els. Otherwise, it handles much the same.

```js
// Store references that all functions can use.
var resultEl = document.querySelector(".resultSet"),
  plusMinusWidgets = document.querySelectorAll(".plusMinusThing");

// Attach the handlers to each plus-minus thing
for (var i = 0; i < plusMinusWidgets.length; i++) {
  plusMinusWidgets[i].querySelector(".minusBtn").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  plusMinusWidgets[i].querySelector(".plusBtn").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  plusMinusWidgets[i].querySelector(".count").addEventListener("change", changeHandler);
}

/*****
 * both plus and minus use the same function, but value is set by the class of the
 *  button
 *****/
function clickHandler(event) {
  // reference to the count input field
  var countEl = event.target.parentNode.querySelector(".count");
  if (event.target.className.match(/\bminusBtn\b/)) {
    countEl.value = Number(countEl.value) - 1;
  } else if (event.target.className.match(/\bplusBtn\b/)) {
    countEl.value = Number(countEl.value) + 1;
  }
  // When we programmatically change the value, we need to manually trigger
  //  the change event.
  triggerEvent(countEl, "change");
};

/*****
 * changeHandler() processes whenever a plusMinusWidget's count el is changed.
 *  It iterates over all plusMinusWidgets, gets their count, and outputs that
 *  to the given resultEl input field.
 *****/
function changeHandler(event) {
  // remove all value from the result el.
  resultEl.value = 0;
  /******
   * Here is the only functional change, per your comment. Rather
   *  concatenating a string, you want to sum values of the 
   *  plusMinusWidget. To do this, we need to cast the value of each
   *  plusMinusWidget to a Number value, and add that to the Number
   *  value of the resultEl.
   *****/
  for (var i = 0; i < plusMinusWidgets.length; i++) {
    // Add the current plusMinusWidget value to the resultEl value.
    resultEl.value = Number(resultEl.value) + Number(plusMinusWidgets[i].querySelector('.count').value);

  }

};

/*****
 * triggerEvent() -- function to trigger an HTMLEvent on a given element.
 *  similar to jquery's trigger(), simply a convenience function. Not the
 *  point of this exercise.
 *****/

function triggerEvent(el, type){
   if ('createEvent' in document) {
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

.plusMinusThing {
  display: block;
  width: 206px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.plusMinusThing input {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="results">
  <input type="text" class="resultSet" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="plusMinusThing">
  <input type="button" class="minusBtn" value="-">
  <input type="text" value="0" class="count">
  <input type="button" class="plusBtn" value="+">
  <br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="plusMinusThing">
  <input type="button" class="minusBtn" value="-">
  <input type="text" value="0" class="count">
  <input type="button" class="plusBtn" value="+">
  <br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="plusMinusThing">
  <input type="button" class="minusBtn" value="-">
  <input type="text" value="0" class="count">
  <input type="button" class="plusBtn" value="+">
  <br>
</fieldset>
```

The point of all this, either way, is that the complex element represented by plusMinusWidget (the fieldSet containing the plusBtn, the minusBtn and the count input) should be self-contained. I don't want to have to try to figure which button refers to what element -- the buttons are part of the complex elements, and they refer to their own count input. Try to use the DOM hierarchy to make your life easier, whenever possible.

**EXTRA CREDIT: Because I'm a fan of simplifying, I wanted to create this same effect with objects. The advantage to this approach is, I can create a PlusMinusWidget, and then create as many instances of it as I like. The page designer doesn't have to be aware of my programmatic elements, she simply has to create a container for them. The following code would handle everything else.

```js
/******
 * Constructor for my plusMinusWidget complex input element.
 *  At this point, it contains two functions:
 *  -- __init() initializes the DOM elements and the event listeners for
 *            the current PlusMinusWidget. The double-underscore is a
 *            lazy attempt at hiding the function.
 *  -- getHtml() returns the DOM content, so we can append that into
 *            the DOM itself.
 *
 * It is designed to be used within a containing element, as i use that
 *    to handle the recalculation event. I don't want the PlusMinusWidgets
 *    to have to be aware of much. Ideally, I would have created a container
 *    complex widget to handle the event listening for the recalculate
 *    event, but this was purely a prototype. More refinement is always
 *    an option.
 ******/
 
var PlusMinusWidget = function(id){
  // when the new PlusMinusWidget gets created, we
  //  create the DOM node containing everything, and then
  //  we initialize the DOM content and the listeners.
  this.DOMEl = $("<fieldset>").addClass("plusMinusWidget");
  this.__init(id);
};

$.extend(PlusMinusWidget.prototype, {
  // init() gets called above, when we create the DOM structure and
  //   set up the listeners.
  __init: function(id){
    // create a reference to the DOMEl. This isn't necessary for creating
    //  the structures, but within the listeners, we can't use 'this.DOMEl'
    //  as the value of 'this' has changed. Thus, we create a reference here.
    var domEl = this.DOMEl;
    // If we don't get an ID, we don't want to error out, so set it to "".
    var id = id || "";
    
    // The three DOM components that will be part of the PlusMinusWidget
    var minusEl = $("<input>")
                   .addClass("minusBtn")
                   .attr("type", "button")
                   .val("-");
    var valueEl = $("<input>")
                   .addClass("quantity")
                   .attr("type", "text")
                   .val("0");
    var plusEl = $("<input>")
                   .addClass("plusBtn")
                   .attr("type", "button")
                   .val("+");
    
    // set the ID of the PlusMinusWidget, and insert the DOM els.
    domEl.attr("id", id).append(minusEl, valueEl, plusEl);
    
    /*****
     * Setting up the listeners. There are three events that
     *  are integral to this PlusMinusWidget, and one that is
     *  more external and could be handled elsewhere.
     *  .minusBtn.click
     *  .plusBtn.click
     *  .quantity.change / .quantity.keyup
     *
     *  ... and the external listener is the parent node's
     *      'plusMinus:recalculate', a custom event that we can
     *      monitor and handle.
     *****/
    domEl.on("click", ".minusBtn", function(){
      valueEl.val(Number(valueEl.val() ) -1);
      valueEl.trigger("change");
    }).on("click", ".plusBtn", function(){
      valueEl.val(Number(valueEl.val() ) + 1);
      valueEl.trigger("change");
    }).on("change keyup", ".quantity", function(){
      domEl.parent().trigger("plusMinus:recalculate");
    });
    /*****
     * the plusMinus:recalculate event is called on the DOMEl's parent
     *   node. This is the only el that should be aware of its child nodes,
     *   thus the only el that should have access to its descendant 
     *   PlusMinusWidget nodes. 
     *****/
    $(document).on("plusMinus:recalculate", domEl.parent(), function(){
      resultEl.val(0);
      $(".plusMinusWidget").each(function(){
        resultEl.val(Number(resultEl.val()) + Number($(this).find(".quantity").val()) )
      })
    })
  },
  getHtml: function(){
    return this.DOMEl;
  }
})
/******************
 * Everything above could be moved into
 *   a separate file, and saved as
 *   plusMinus.widget.js (for example). 
 *   That piece can be hidden from the end
 *   user -- all they need to know is the
 *   code below: how to initialize the 
 *   PlusMinusWidget object, and how to 
 *   use its sole public function, getHtml.
 *
 ******************/
// So here, we actually create an array of our PlusMinusWidget objects.
//  As each is created, it's initialized and its DOM el is populated.
var plusMinusWidgets = [new PlusMinusWidget("firstQty"), new PlusMinusWidget("secondQty"), new PlusMinusWidget("thirdQty")];

// Create the reference to our results input and to the container itself.
var resultEl = $(".resultSet");
var plusMinusContainer = $(".container");

// iterate over the array we created just above, and for each member of the
//   array, stick its DOM structure into the containing element. Note that this
//   handles all the DOM, all the listeners, everything. 
$.each(plusMinusWidgets, function(){
  plusMinusContainer.append(this.getHtml());
})
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}
.plusMinusThing {
  display: block;
  width: 206px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.plusMinusThing input {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="results">
  <input type="text" class="resultSet" />
</fieldset>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

This was created with jQuery again, simply because it does simplify the creation of objects and listeners, but its not entirely necessary. Again, the beauty of this approach is that the DOM creation and event listener bits are completely hidden 'under the hood.' The end user really only needs to know how to initialize the PlusMinusWidget, and how to pop it into the DOM. Everything else happens seamlessly.

And again, this is just another approach. Not good, better or best, simply a thought experiment.

Comment: #Snowmonkey thanks, have run your code snippets and both are nearly what I'm after apart from the two counters need to show the single total of all three button/counters i.e not 1 1 1 but 3.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using querySelectorAll to find every element of the class count, I would give each input box an ID such as "input1", "input2", "input3".

Then I would change the plus and minus functions to accept a parameter to indicate which row it was from.

Finally, I would update the correct input with the new value.

It would look something like this:

```
<input type="button" value="-" onclick="minus(1)">
<input type="text" value="0" class="count" id="input1">
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="plus(1)"<br><br>

function minus(int row){
var inputElem = document.getElementById("input" + row.ToString());
inputElem.value--; 
}
```

Comment: A few issues with this -- first, the count has just become the same value across all count elements. Instead, you want to set the value of THE COUNT INPUT to its value plus or minus one, assuming I've read this right. Otherwise, your solution should work, though I'm not a fan of hard-coded DOM events. ;)

Comment: True, thanks. Ya me neither but was just thinking of the simplest solution